# Is the set of functions on a compact manifold a Hilbert space?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth compact manifold without boundary and let $\omega \in \Omega_M^{\mathrm{top}}$ be a volume form.
Let $C^k(M, \mathbb{R})$ be the set of functions $M \to \mathbb{R}$ whose first $k$ derivatives exist and are continuous.
We may then endow $C^k(M, \mathbb{R})$ with an inner-product
$$\langle f, g \rangle := \int_M fg \omega.$$
**Question:** Is $(C^k(M, \mathbb{R}), \langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle)$ a Hilbert space for some choice of $k$? Does the answer change for some specific $\omega$ (e.g. coming from a Riemannian metric)?

Comment: The $C^k$ spaces are never Hilbert Spaces with the scalar product you wrote down, because they are not complete in the induced norm (-> exercise for you...). If you want to have Hilbert Spaces, you have to look at the Sobolev spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comment by Thomas, let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and choose any continuous non smooth function in $U$ whose support in contained in compact subset of $U$, then we can approximate it by smooth functions so that their integrals tend to be equal as we go on. Now, to do this in a compact manifold, you just need to choose a chart and you're back to the previous case.

Now, this chosen approximation gives a cauchy sequence whose limit is not smooth, so the space isn't complete.